# python pandas - getting a column value after running idxmax / argmax

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to go through some data to find which category of products had the highest revenue.

I can get the actual total revenue of the category with the highest revenue by running:

```
max_revenue_by_cat = summer_transactions.groupby('item_category_id')['total_sales'].sum().max()
```

But how do I then get what category_id that max revenue belonged to? i.e. the category_id with the highest number of `total_sales`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - it is same as OP code.

Comment: Uh, then `df.set_index('item_category_id').total_sales.sum(level=0).sort_values().iloc[[-1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using coldspeed's data :-)

```
(df.groupby('item_category_id').total_sales.sum()).loc[lambda x : x==x.max()]


Out[11]: 
item_category_id
1    440
Name: total_sales, dtype: int64
```

Comment: but OP need value of index and of column too ;)

Comment: @Wen - What do ypu think about [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870988/python-pandas-getting-a-column-value-after-running-idxmax-argmax/47871136#comment82708740_47871136) ?

Comment: @jezrael ummm, my real answer is `(df.groupby('item_category_id').total_sales.sum()).loc[lambda x : x==x.max()]`

Comment: @wen - I'd actually accept this as an answer if you convert it.

Comment: @mheavers you mean the order ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `set_index` + `sum(level=0)` + `sort_values` + `iloc` to index the first item.

```
df

   item_category_id  total_sales
0                 1          100
1                 1           10
2                 0          200
3                 2           20
4                 1          300
5                 0          100
6                 1           30
7                 2          400

r = df.set_index('item_category_id')\
      .total_sales.sum(level=0)\
      .sort_values(ascending=False)\
      .iloc[[0]]

item_category_id
1    440
Name: total_sales, dtype: int64
```

If you want this as a mini-dataframe, call `reset_index` on the result -

```
r.reset_index()

   item_category_id  total_sales
0                 1          440
```

---

**Details**

```
df.set_index('item_category_id').total_sales.sum(level=0)

item_category_id
1    440
0    300
2    420
Name: total_sales, dtype: int64
```

Here, the category with the largest sum is `1`. Usually, with a small number of groups, the `sort_values` call takes negligible time, so this should be pretty performant.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html), but for return index add `[]`:

```
summer_transactions = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                                    'total_sales':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                                    'item_category_id':list('aaabbb')})


df = summer_transactions.groupby('item_category_id')['total_sales'].sum()

s = df.loc[[df.idxmax()]]
print (s)
item_category_id
b    15
Name: total_sales, dtype: int64


df = df.loc[[df.idxmax()]].reset_index(name='col')
print (df)
  item_category_id  col
0                b   15
```

Comment: Yes. I agree, first part of answers is same. But OP need second part and it is diffetent, so I think it is OK.